# Transform javascript array of object to object with keys and array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects I need to transform into new objects. some value as keys and an array of values.

```
const data = [
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'group',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    type: 'group',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 3
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 4
  }
]
```

and the desired result is

```
const result = {
  user: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  group: [1, 2]
}
```

what I've tried using `reduced` but it not what I'm expected.

```
const result = data.reduce((acc, { type, ...obj }) => {
  acc[type] = data.map(item => item.id)
  return acc;
}, {})

result = { user: [ 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4 ], group: [ 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each iterate, you check if the accumulate object has the type, if yes, push the iterated element's id to the existing array, else init the array

```js
const data = [
  {
    type: "user",
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    type: "user",
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    type: "group",
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    type: "group",
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    type: "user",
    id: 3,
  },
  {
    type: "user",
    id: 4,
  },
]

const res = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (acc[el.type]) {
    acc[el.type].push(el.id)
  } else {
    acc[el.type] = [el.id]
  }

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're doing functional programming with predefined reducer functions, `reduce` is usually an overcomplicated tool. Just use a loop.

In this case, you'd start with an object with `user` and `group` properties that have empty arrays, then add to the right array using a dynamic property name:

```
const result = { user: [], group: [] };
for (const {type, id} of data) {
    result[type].push(id);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'group',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    type: 'group',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 3
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 4
  }
];

const result = { user: [], group: [] };
for (const {type, id} of data) {
    result[type].push(id);
}
console.log(result);
```

If the `type` values aren't known in advance, add the arrays dynamically:

```
const result = { user: [], group: [] };
for (const {type, id} of data) {
    if (!result[type]) {
        result[type] = [];
    }
    result[type].push(id);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'group',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    type: 'group',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 3
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 4
  }
];

const result = { user: [], group: [] };
for (const {type, id} of data) {
    if (!result[type]) {
        result[type] = [];
    }
    result[type].push(id);
}
console.log(result);
```

If you like being *really* terse, you could use [the new `??=` operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-logical-assignment) to add the array when it's not there yet (for me, in this case, it's going too far and losing clarity):

```
const result = { user: [], group: [] };
for (const {type, id} of data) {
    (result[type] ??= []).push(id);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const data = [
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'group',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    type: 'group',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 3
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 4
  }
];

const result = { user: [], group: [] };
for (const {type, id} of data) {
    (result[type] ??= []).push(id);
}
console.log(result);
```

---

You *can* shoehorn this into a `reduce` (because you can shoehorn *any* array operation into a `reduce`), but doing so doesn't buy you anything. Here's that first one using `reduce` instead of a loop:

```
const result = data.reduce((acc, {type, id}) => {
    acc[type].push(id);
    return acc;
}, {user: [], group: []});
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'group',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    type: 'group',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 3
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 4
  }
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, {type, id}) => {
    acc[type].push(id);
    return acc;
}, {user: [], group: []});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the property does not exists and push `id` to it.

```js
const
    data = [{ type: 'user', id: 1 }, { type: 'user', id: 2 }, { type: 'group', id: 1 }, { type: 'group', id: 2 }, { type: 'user', id: 3 }, { type: 'user', id: 4 }],
    result = data.reduce((acc, { type, id }) => {
        acc[type] ??= [];
        acc[type].push(id);
        return acc;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: UV. When did the `??=` came into being. I see that there is also `||=` - is it old or new?

Comment: @OriDrori - They were added in ES2021, [here's the (finished) proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-logical-assignment).

Answer (score 0):

If the property doesn't exist on the accumulator add it, and if it does push the `id` into it:

```js
const data = [{"type":"user","id":1},{"type":"user","id":2},{"type":"group","id":1},{"type":"group","id":2},{"type":"user","id":3},{"type":"user","id":4}];

const result = data.reduce((acc, { type, id }) => {
  if(!acc[type]) acc[type] = [];
  
  acc[type].push(id);

  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

A vanilla version of `groupBy()`

```
const groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x.id);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
```

You could easily call group by a key using,

```
const result = groupBy(data, 'type');
```

Full code:

```
const groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x.id);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

const data = [
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'group',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    type: 'group',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 3
  },
  {
    type: 'user',
    id: 4
  }
]

const result = groupBy(data, 'type');

console.log(result); // { group: [1, 2], user: [1, 2, 3, 4] }
```

Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution using `Object.fromEntries` to build the skeleton for the result object (with empty arrays). Then a simple loop can populate those arrays, and you're done:

```js
let data = [{ type: 'user', id: 1 }, { type: 'user', id: 2 }, { type: 'group', id: 1 }, { type: 'group', id: 2 }, { type: 'user', id: 3 }, { type: 'user', id: 4 }];
let result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({type}) => [type, []]));
for (let {type, id} of data) result[type].push(id);

console.log(result);
```